# Incorrect total using SUM of DATEDIFF results

Tags: sql-server

When i run a few `DateDiff(SECOND, value1, value2)` it returns a lists of values

93, 185, 1879  which totals 2157 sum with the calc and with SUM()

However, when i use `DateDiff(SECOND, firstValue1, lastValue2)` returned 2476

A example of the problem is:

```
declare @testTable table
(
    DateD float
)
insert into @testTable
select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 22:40:29.847', '2015-08-12 23:11:48.000')
UNION
select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 23:11:48.510', '2015-08-12 23:14:53.000')
UNION
select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 23:20:12.147', '2015-08-12 23:21:45.000')

select sum(DateD)from @testTable

select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 22:40:29.847', '2015-08-12 23:21:45.000')
```

What is my fault?

Thanks.

Comment: If `DateD` is a `SECOND` datediff, Why not `INTEGER`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 6min19s gap between row 2 and row 3.

If you add this, it works fine:

```
select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 22:40:29.847', '2015-08-12 23:11:48.000')
UNION
select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 23:11:48.510', '2015-08-12 23:14:53.000')
**UNION**
**select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 23:14:53.000', '2015-08-12 23:20:12.147')**
UNION
select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 23:20:12.147', '2015-08-12 23:21:45.000')
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, quite simply, there are gaps in your time series.

A naive `DATEDIFF(MIN, MAX)` ignores the fact that there is roughly a 6-minute gap between your second and third rows.

Think about it this way: If you go to school from Monday-Friday, how many days did you attend in June? Not 30, because some of those days in June were Saturday and Sunday (and maybe holidays and PD days, too).

Answer (score 1):

The fault I am seeing is your SUM of

`select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 22:40:29.847', '2015-08-12 23:21:45.000')`

is not the same as the sum of all 3 of those datediff values.

Your 3 Unions all contain seperate time values and do not cross over to the next value, this will cause the SUM of ALL values to be bigger then your 3 seperated values.

Example:

`select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 22:40:29.847', '2015-08-12 23:11:48.000')
UNION
select datediff(SECOND, '2015-08-12 23:11:48.510', '2015-08-12 23:14:53.000')`

This is specifically taking the sum of VALUES 1 and VALUES 2
however, your 2nd select statement is not the EXACT ending point of your 1st select statement `'2015-08-12 23:11:48.000') -->(SECOND, '2015-08-12 23:11:48.510'` ending point being 23:11:48.000 and 2nd union starting point is 21:11:48.510.

Answer (score 0):

Your periods are not completely contiguous.

Look at it this way. If you add the period in hours between 7PM and 10PM to the period in hours between 7PM and 9PM, and then add this result to the period in hours between 7PM and 8 PM, then how many hours do you get?

7-10 = 3 hours
7-9  = 2 hours
7-8  = 1 hour  => (3 + 2 + 1) hours = 6 hours

The gap between 7PM - 10PM in hours is only 3 hours. Why should 6 = 3 in this case? They should not as they do not in your example.

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE ( DateD FLOAT );

INSERT INTO @testTable
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(HOUR , '2015-08-12 19:00:00.000' , '2015-08-12 22:00:00.000')  -- 3hrs

    UNION

    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(HOUR , '2015-08-12 19:00:00.00' , '2015-08-12 21:00:00.000')   -- 2hrs

    UNION

    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(HOUR , '2015-08-12 19:00:00.000' , '2015-08-12 20:00:00.000'); -- 1hr

SELECT
    SUM(DateD)
FROM
    @testTable;

SELECT
    DATEDIFF(HOUR , '2015-08-12 19:00:00.000' , '2015-08-12 22:00:00.000'); -- 3hr
```